# Database is not created on docker compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm following the [docs of mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/). It says that the db should be created if it find a .sql in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d.
I'm working on a Ubuntu Server in a Oracle Virtual BOX VM.
My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=database // tried with MYSQL_DATABASE and without this line

    volumes:
      - "db_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - ".database/initdb/dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sql"
    # networks:
    #   - network

volumes:
  db_data:
```

My initdb.sql looks like this (the one that should work in the end looks different but out of simplicity I reduced it to the max and could not even this simple one working):

```
CREATE DATABASE NEWDB;
```

I honestly don't know where to look or what to do now because everywhere I looked for a possible solution I found that this is the bare minimum example that should work.

I tried to restarted docker, deleted all containers, images and volumes, modified the initdb.sql into:

```
CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database TO user;
```

but the database is not initialized when I docker compose up.
I looked up the container and the initdb.sql was there.

EDIT: It somehow worked, when I docker compose up with MARIADB_DATABASE=database but the script initdb.sql still doesn't work and it's the most important thing because it set's up the whole database.
(NOTE: On top of that I want to set up another PHP-container that runs a PHP-script in order to collect data that is being stored in the above MariaDB-container. The MariaDB is connected with a website that calls data from the container)

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm using the following stack and it works fine for me.

###### php-apache:

This is an Apache server that runs all my `php` scripts. You can place your scripts in `./src` directory and it will automatically be mounted to `DocumentRoot` directory of the `Apache` server.

###### db:

This the latest docker container of `MariaDb`

###### adminer:

This is the lite-weight database browser which I use for creating and altering my databases. You can just visit `localhost:8081` and then enter the following credentials. It becomes simpler to manage the databases this way.

> username: root 
> password: example

```yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:8.0-apache
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
```

###### Dockerfile:

This is a simple docker container which is extended from the base `php:8.0-apache` image, with `mysql` extensions installed in it for `PDO` support.

```yaml
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

###### P.S:

Here you'll have to create all your databases manually via GUI of `Adminer`. But if you prefer `SQL` queries via `initdb.sql` then be my guest. I've just provided this configuration as a suggestion.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. The PHP part looks interesting. What is in the Dockerfile to run the PHP script? Do you connect to the Docker container like a normal database or is there something special to consider?

Comment: ah yes, how silly of me to miss the `Dockerfile`. I'll update the answer with it. Yes, I do connect to the docker container like a normal database system. Your `PHP` scripts will be able to connect to the db container by using `$servername = "db";` in the connection string. Also, you can modify the database externally by accessing `adminer`. Just a small note, I use this database system only within this current project. It depends on you if you wish to use it as a global db system across all projects.

Comment: Thank you. That's not exactly what I need but it helps.
I would upvote your comments but I need two more points for that. If you upvote two of my comments I could upvote yours.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why you move your scripts from ./src to /var/www/html, run the dockerfile and furnage your php-container since I cannot see any script that is executed in the container? 
Did you manage to execute a PHP-script in the PHP-container that e.g. stores data in the mariadb docker container?

Comment: That's the mount volume. It maps the host machines directory to the docker directory. If you ask, why I do that? It's because that's the Apache DocumentRoot directory. Only the files placed in this directory will be executed by the php docker container. Also, yes I am inserting data into the db container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you misunderstood my question. My question was more about wanting to know how the script is executed in the container. How to mount a script in a Docker container is clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution. I used a base image of laravel (installed the laravel project with <curl -s "https://laravel.build/project-name?with=mariadb" | sudo bash> and modified it a little bit. So here's the docker-compose.yml:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        container_name: 'mariadb-10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mariadb:
        driver: local
```

Here you can see that the "10-create-testing-database.sh" is executed on startup. I tested this container and it created a database, so I just had to modify it a little bit and now the container creates a database and tables on container startup. Here's the "10-create-testing-database.sh":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_name;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`testing%\`.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%';
    
    USE database_name;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(  
    table_entries ...
    );
EOSQL
```

I still don't know why my initial setup did not work. The only difference I see is that this working file is a .sh and the not working one is a .sql (this does not make sence to me but it what it is).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=14

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && gpg --recv-key 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c \
    && gpg --export 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c > /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

Comment: Please also share the Dockerfile of your modified image.